# using type on ordered tag not working with list in html 5

Tags: html

Please consider the following HTML code that I am using inside the body tag:

```
<ol>
    <li>This is First List Item</li>
    <ol>
        <li>Nested List Item</li>
    </ol>
 </ol>

<ol>
    <li>This is Second List Item</li>
    <ol type = "A">
        <li>Nested List Item with different type</li>
    </ol>
</ol>
```

I am using following style for this :

```
ol {
  list-style-type: none;
  counter-reset: item;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


li {
  display: table;
  counter-increment: item;
  margin-bottom: 0.6em;
}

li:before {
    content: counters(item, ".") ". ";
    display: table-cell;
    padding-right: 0.6em;    
}

li li {
    margin: 0;
}

li li:before {
    content: counters(item, ".") " ";
}
```

I get the following output :

```
1 This is First List Item
1.1 Nested List Item
1 This is Second List Item
1.1 Nested List Item with different type
```

I was expecting the last `1.1` result to be starting from `A`as I have mentioned the type for itbut it's not working. What's wrong I am doing here?

Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xnb7kjfh/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ol), the `ol` and `ul` elements can only contain `li` element. That is one thing done, second is your CSS. The `display: table;` is messing things up along with `list-style-type: none;`. Use developer console to figure you the rest.

```
<ol>
    <li>This is Second List Item</li>
    <li>
        <ol type = "A">
            <li>Nested List Item with different type</li>
            <li>xyz</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
</ol>
```